# Pandas dataframe that consists of only grouped by rows with a counter higher than X

Tags: python, pandas

I want to show count the number of groups I have in one column and then only show those groups that have more than a specific number.

Consider this example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'ColA': 'A A A B B C C C C D E E F F F F F F F G G H'.split(),
        'ColB': '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2'.split()
    }
)
```

If I group it like so:

```
print df.groupby(['ColA']).agg(['count'])
```

I get output like this:

```
      ColB
     count
ColA      
A        3
B        2
C        4
D        1
E        2
F        7
G        2
H        1
```

Now, if I want to only show the rows from above when the count is over 2, how would I do that? I would expect output without `B`, `D`, `E`, `G` or `H`

I've attempted the following two lines and both return the same error:

```
print df.loc[df.groupby(['ColA']).agg(['count']) > 2]
print df.loc[df.groupby(['ColA']).agg(['count'])['ColB'] > 2]
```

With the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/scratches/scratch_3", line 11, in <module>
    print df.loc[df.groupby(['ColA']).agg(['count'])['ColB'] > 2]
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1189, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_axis(key, axis=0)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1321, in _getitem_axis
    raise ValueError('Cannot index with multidimensional key')
ValueError: Cannot index with multidimensional key
```

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32487656/189134) provided by PabTorre does not appear to work on newer versions of pandas. I am using `0.16.2` When I utilize that answer I receive the following error on this line:

```
print df_count[df_count.values>2]
```

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/scratches/scratch_3", line 10, in <module>
    print df_count[df_count.values>2]
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 1791, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_array(key)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 1833, in _getitem_array
    return self.take(indexer, axis=0, convert=False)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1358, in take
    convert=True, verify=True)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 3275, in take
    axis=axis, allow_dups=True)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 3162, in reindex_indexer
    for blk in self.blocks]
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 857, in take_nd
    allow_fill=True, fill_value=fill_value)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\common.py", line 844, in take_nd
    func(arr, indexer, out, fill_value)
  File "pandas\src\generated.pyx", line 5779, in pandas.algos.take_2d_axis1_object_object (pandas\algos.c:107426)
  File "stringsource", line 614, in View.MemoryView.memoryview_cwrapper (pandas\algos.c:187433)
  File "stringsource", line 321, in View.MemoryView.memoryview.__cinit__ (pandas\algos.c:184022)
ValueError: buffer source array is read-only
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your last query:

```
print df.loc[df.groupby(['ColA']).agg(['count']) > 2]
```

Is that df.loc[] is expecting a series of 22 boolean objects. 
Instead, it is getting a series of 8 objects:

```
>>> df.groupby(['ColA']).agg(['count']) > 2
       ColB
      count
ColA       
A      True
B     False
C      True
D     False
E     False
F      True
G     False
H     False
```

So it doesn't know how to put them together.

But there is a solution. :)

First, let's assign the aggregate df to a new object.

```
>>> df_count = df.groupby(['ColA']).agg(['count']).ColB
>>> df_count.columns=['ColB']
```

Then we can easily filter it

```
>>> df_count[df_count.ColB.values>2]
       ColB

ColA       
A         3
C         4
F         7
```

We can then use that filtered df to go back and filter the original df

```
>>> df_filtered=df_count[df_count.ColB.values>2]
>>> df[df.ColA.isin(df_filtered.index)]
   ColA ColB
0     A    1
1     A    2
2     A    3
5     C    6
6     C    7
7     C    8
8     C    9
12    F    3
13    F    4
14    F    5
15    F    6
16    F    7
17    F    8
18    F    9
```

Comment: On `df_filtered = df_count[df_count.values>2]`, I receive `ValueError: buffer source array is read-only`

Comment: that's odd... It runs fine here on pandas 0.14. 
What version are you using?

can you print df_count[df_count.values>2]?

Comment: I'm using pandas `0.16.2`

Comment: yeah, the functionality seems to have changed in pandas 0.16. 
I made some changes and tested them on wakari using pd '0.16.1' it seems to work now.